# Visual Studio 2013. dbml file not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-sql, dbml

I am working on a Visual Studio project that uses ASP.NET/C# with LinqToSql.

All has been going fine, until some changes were made to one of the database tables.

After that, the Table in question was removed from the DBML database diagram, and the new version added back in using the Server Explorer.

Trouble is, VS2013 still does not see the new fields, and will not compile if I reference them. The new table structure is clearly visible in the DBML database diagram.

Comment: rename the table - rebuild - rename back - try again?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your file in solution explorer and select Run custom tools and see if it is getting updated.

Comment: Run custom tool did nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Rebuild your project and you should see the changes.

Comment: rebuild makes no difference.

Comment: Had you saved changes when you deleted the table?

Comment: Deleted table. Saved changes. Added new table back in. Saved changes. Still not there.

Comment: I ended up manually editing the designer.cs file behind the database dbml file. Finally got it working that way.