# SQL Server 2008 : all of my tables are missing

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have connected to a database server and a whole bunch of tables I was looking at yesterday are missing.

If I log on to the same database from a different PC in the same network, using the same username & password, those tables are visible.

I had another recent SQL problem which may or may not be connected that I was unable to resolve: [Visual Studio 2013. dbml file not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503626/visual-studio-2013-dbml-file-not-updating)

Comment: Very unclear what you mean by missing.  Look at sys.tables.  Attempt to write a query against a "missing" table.

Comment: Might be on to something here. I ran this: SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,name AS table_name FROM sys.tables , and got this response: Msg 823, Level 24, State 2, Procedure objects$, Line 2
The operating system returned error 64(The specified network name is no longer available.)